# using separate matrices in a loop and saving the results in a data frame

Tags: r, loops, igraph

I have a few matrices that all of them are the same in number of rows and columns and dimanames of them are exactly the same too. I read them like this for example

```
a<-read.csv("a.txt",row.names = 1,header=T,sep="\t")
b<-read.csv("b.txt",row.names = 1,header=T,sep="\t")
c<-read.csv("c.txt",row.names = 1,header=T,sep="\t")
d<-read.csv("d.txt",row.names = 1,header=T,sep="\t")
e<-read.csv("e.txt",row.names = 1,header=T,sep="\t")
```

Now I want to get similarity index between a & b, a & c,...,b & c, ..., c & d, d
& e using this code

```
library(igraph)
library(BiRewire)

jaccard.index<-birewire.similarity( a,b)
```

Then I want to save the result as a data frame like this for example

```
mat1    mat2    simil.index
a   b   0.9142
a   c   0.8126
a   d   0.5066
b   e   0.9526
```

I don't know how can I use these separate matrices in a loop and saving the result like that. Anyone help me on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare the function to compute pairwise similarities

```
myfun <- function(x, y) {

  birewire.similarity(eval(parse(text = x)), eval(parse(text = y)))

}
```

Build the possible combinations (you said your matrices are named as the first 5 letters of the alphabet, but you can put any names in place of `letters[1:5]`):

```
myletters <- combn(letters[1:5], 2)
```

Build the dataframe binding by column the combinations and the results of the function that is applied to such combinations:

```
data.frame(t(myletters), 
           simil.index = mapply(myfun, myletters[1,], myletters[2,]))
```

Comment: That was great . Really thank you @Davide Passaretti